# How can I get my Web Proxy IP Address from command line?

Tags: curl, proxy, terminal

Terminal and Safari give me different IPs from [ip4.icanhazip.com](http://ip4.icanhazip.com) when my Web Proxy is active.

Browser visits [ip4.icanhazip.com](http://ip4.icanhazip.com) results in `9.8.7.6` (my proxy IP).

Terminal curl's the same link: `curl ip4.icanhazip.com` results in `1.2.3.4` (my ISP network ip)

```
Network IP: 1.2.3.4
Proxy IP: 9.8.7.6
```

Assume `Web Proxy (HTTP)` is setup correctly on Mac OS X via `System Preferences -> Network -> Advanced -> Proxies`

Is it possible to get the browser/proxy IP from command line?

Desired output:

```
$ curl ip4.icanhazip.com
9.8.7.6
```

Obviously I can setup Terminal to use the same proxy. But I'm trying to find out what the browser ip is from terminal. **NOT** the terminal's external ip address.